# WebDriver Exception Selenium Python on redirecting url on default profile of chrome session?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my error screen

[Error Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuqcp.png)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 2
      1 # Create a new instance of the Chrome driver with the specified options
----> 2 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
      4 # Add a delay before opening the URL
      5 time.sleep(3)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py:49, in WebDriver.__init__(self, options, service, keep_alive)
     45 self.keep_alive = keep_alive
     47 self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, self.options)
---> 49 super().__init__(
     50     DesiredCapabilities.CHROME["browserName"],
     51     "goog",
     52     self.options,
     53     self.service,
     54     self.keep_alive,
     55 )

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py:54, in ChromiumDriver.__init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, options, service, keep_alive)
     51 self.service.start()
     53 try:
---> 54     super().__init__(
     55         command_executor=ChromiumRemoteConnection(
     56             remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
...
```

I am using selenium 4.10. and chrome browser version is 114

This is the python script

```
   from selenium import webdriver
   import time  
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

   user_data_dir = 'C:/Users/saura/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/'

   options = Options()
   options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={user_data_dir}')  
   options.add_argument(f'--profile-directory=Default')  
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)  
   time.sleep(3)  
   driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Basically, I want to run the url in the currently logged Chrome session with the default profile.

Comment: Which Selenium version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The WebDriverException you are encountering seems to be related to the version incompatibility between Selenium and Chrome. Selenium 4.1.0 might not be fully compatible with Chrome version 114. You can try below few options:

Update Selenium:

pip install --upgrade selenium

Or, you can try downgrading your Chrome browser to a version that is compatible with Selenium 4.1.0.

or, Instead of managing the Chrome WebDriver executable manually, you can use WebDriverManager.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your path includes space between part of "User Data". Another posibility is nothing saving account data in your path.